# Cartesian Product of a finite sequence of potentially infinite sequences

Tags: haskell, clojure, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, cartesian-product

## The Problem

I need to create a function that, when given a finite sequence of potentially infinite sequences, it produces the sequence that is their "cartesian product".

i.e. given the sequence

```
'((1 2) (3 4))
```

the function produces (some ordering of):

```
'((1 3) (1 4) (2 3) (2 4)
```

**Importantly**, for every `p` in the list of cartesian products `ps`, there must be some natural number `n` such that `(= p (last (take n ps)))`. Or, informally, you only need to iterate through the sequence a finite amount to reach any element in it.

This condition becomes important when dealing with infinite lists.

## Solution in Haskell

In Haskell, this is how I would have done it:

```hs
interleave           :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave [] ys     = ys
interleave (x:xs) ys = x : interleave ys xs

combine :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
combine = foldr prod [[]]
  where
    prod xs css = foldr1 interleave [ [x:cs | cs <- css] | x <- xs]
```

And calling it you get the following:

```hs
combine [[0..] [0..]] = [[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[,1,0],[2,0,0],[0,0,1],[1,1,0],...
```

## Solution in Clojure

And so I attempted to replicate this in Clojure, like so, (It's pretty much a direct translation):

```lisp
(defn interleave
  "Returns a lazy sequence of the interleavings of sequences `xs` and `ys`
  (both potentially infinite), leaving no elements discarded."
  [xs ys]
  (lazy-seq
    (if-let [[x & xs*] (seq xs)]
      (cons x (interleave ys xs*))
      ys)))

(defn interleave*
  "Converts a sequence of potentially infinite sequences into its lazy
  interleaving."
  [xss]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [[xs & xss*] (seq xss)]
      (interleave xs (interleave* xss*)))))

(defn combine
  "Takes a finite sequence of potentially infinite sequences, and combines
  them to produce a possibly infinite sequence of their cartesian product."
  [xss]
  (if-let [[xs & xss*] (seq xss)]
    (interleave*
      (for [x xs]
        (for [cs (combine xss*)]
          (lazy-seq (cons x cs)))))
    '(()) ))
```

But when I run:

```
(take 1 (combine [(range) (range)]))
```

I get:

```
StackOverflowError   cfg.util/combine/iter--3464--3468/fn--3469/fn--3470/iter--3471--3475/fn--3476
```

So, how do I make it lazy enough, so as to avoid the stack overflow? Really, I don't understand how Clojure's lazy sequence model works which is the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution may be algorithmically intractable, reconstructing the sub-sequences time and again, much as the simple Fibonacci function:

```
(defn fib [n]
  (case n
    (0N 1N) n
    (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))
```

... recomputes its precedents.

In any event, the search for `[100 10]` in the cartesian product of `(range)` and `(range)`:

```
(first (filter #{[100 10]} (combine [(range) (range)])))
```

... does not return in a reasonable time.

---

I can offer you a faster though far less elegant solution.

First, a couple of utilities:

[Something from @amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18248031/1562315) to compute the Cartesian product of finite sequences:

```
(defn cart [colls]
  (if (empty? colls)
    '(())
    (for [x (first colls)
          more (cart (rest colls))]
      (cons x more))))
```

A function adapted from the *Clojure Cookbook* to map the values of a map:

```
(defn map-vals [f m] (zipmap (keys m) (map f (vals m))))
```

Now for the function we want, which I've called `enum-cart`, as it enumerates the Cartesian product even of infinite sequences:

```
(defn enum-cart [colls]
  (let [ind-colls (into (sorted-map) (map-indexed (fn [n s] [n (seq s)]) colls))      
        entries ((fn tins [ss] (let [ss (select-keys ss (map key (filter val ss)))]
                                 (lazy-seq
                                   (if (seq ss)
                                     (concat
                                       (map-vals first ss)
                                       (tins (map-vals next ss)))))))
                     ind-colls)
        seens (reductions
                (fn [a [n x]] (update-in a [n] conj x))
                (vec (repeat (count colls) []))
                entries)]
    (mapcat
      (fn [sv [n x]] (cart (assoc sv n [x])))
      seens entries)))
```

The idea is to generate an indexed sequence of entries, going round the non-exhausted sequences. From this we generate a companion sequence of what we have already seen from each sequence. We pairwise combine these two, generating the free cartesian product of the new element with what we have of the other sequences. The answer is the concatenation of these free products.

For example

```
(enum-cart [(range 3) (range 10 15)])
```

... produces

```
((0 10)
 (1 10)
 (0 11)
 (1 11)
 (2 10)
 (2 11)
 (0 12)
 (1 12)
 (2 12)
 (0 13)
 (1 13)
 (2 13)
 (0 14)
 (1 14)
 (2 14))
```

And

```
(first (filter #{[100 10]} (enum-cart [(range) (range)])))
;(100 10)
```

... returns more or less instantly.

---

*Notes*

- Is this better done in *Knuth* or elsewhere? I don't have access to
  it.
- The last non-exhausted sequence need not be kept, as there is nothing
  else to use it.

Comment: You are right in that the time it takes for the sequence to reach `[100 10]` is unreasonable. However, that is not because of repeated work, but because of ordering: Using what is essentially a fold over a list in the definition of `interleave*` introduces a bias towards the last collection given to `combine`: Numbers in that collection rise exponentially faster than in the first collection. For example, `[10 100]` will be reached much more quickly than `[100 10]`. Your solution does look to be a good one though, I'm just having trouble fully understanding it.

Comment: @asQuirreL. Ah! Conversely, as you may have gathered, I have trouble understanding your solution :). Mine proceeds evenly through all the collections - a bit like Cantor's enumeration of the rationals. The way to understand it is to return the `entries` for a few examples, then look at them beside the `seens`. Once the `entries` sequence is constructed, it alone drives the rest of the process.

Comment: I think I've just about wrapped my head around your solution. I've also convinced myself that it traverses the entire space too, and in a rather pleasing almost easy (if it wasn't n-dimensional), by shifting up one in each dimension successively, right? It's very nice. For the record, the solution I gave is about twice as fast, if you don't care that it produces a biased sample. I however, do care, so this looks very promising. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured it out. And the issue is a subtle, but frustrating one. The problem stems from the destructuring I perform, in basically every function: I use this sort of idiom: `[x & xs*] (seq xs)`, however, this realizes the first element of `xs*`, as well as realizing `x`. This behaviour is similar to what you would see if you were to use `first` and `next` to get the head and tail of the list respectively.

Using `first`/`rest` instead of destructuring in this way fixed the stack overflow:

```
(defn interleave
  "Returns a lazy sequence of the interleavings of sequences `xs` and `ys`
  (both potentially infinite), leaving no elements discarded."
  [xs ys]
  (lazy-seq
    (if-let [xs* (seq xs)]
      (cons (first xs*) (interleave ys (rest xs*)))
      ys)))

(defn interleave*
  "Converts a sequence of potentially infinite sequences into its lazy
  interleaving."
  [xss]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [xss* (seq xss)]
      (interleave (first xss*)
                  (interleave* (rest xss*))))))

(defn combine
  "Takes a finite sequence of potentially infinite sequences, and combines
  them to produce a possibly infinite sequence of their cartesian product."
  [xss]
  (if-let [xss* (seq xss)]
    (interleave*
      (for [x (first xss*)]
        (for [cs (combine (rest xss*))]
          (lazy-seq (cons x cs)))))
    '(()) ))
```

And running it, we get:

```
(= (take 5 (combine [(range) (range) (range)]))
   '((0 0 0) (1 0 0) (0 1 0) (2 0 0) (0 0 1)))
```

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246549/cartesian-product-in-clojure). Your solution seems to be too complex for this task.

Comment: @Mark the solution in that question does not deal with infinite sequences. If you look at the accepted answer's definition of `cart` and my definition of `combine` they are very similar, however mine splits the nested iteration into two separate `for` loops, and uses `interleave*` to combine them, in case they were infinite.

Comment: `user> (take 5 (cart [(range) (range) (range)]))
;; => ((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 0 2) (0 0 3) (0 0 4))` what's the problem with it? `range` produces infinite sequences, yet it works. Also, Clojure has standard function [`interleave`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/interleave), which is lazy. Solution in Haskell may be simpler too.

Comment: Ah, I see now, your note 'for every p in the list of cartesian products ...' makes sense here.

Comment: Indeed, and as for `clojure.core/interleave`, it suffers the same problem as my old solution: It induces a Stack Overflow because it is not as lazy as the `interleave` I've defined (It realizes two elements every time it iterates, if you look at the source). Although, when I originally redefined it, it was because I was nervous of its propensity to discard the remaining elements, if one of the sequences was too long.