# How do I iterate through two Sets in Clojure in order to return their Cartesian product?

Tags: clojure, set, cartesian-product

So I take in two Sets and wanna iterate through them in order to return a new set containing the cross product of the two sets.

```
(defn cartesian
  "computes Cartesian product of A and B"

  [A B]
  

  use "set", "for")
```

I'm very new to Clojure so I'm not sure why use "set, "for" is included at all.
But A and B will be Sets. Now I wanna iterate through each one and return the Cartesian product of them. Example:

```
(cartesian #{1 2} #{3 4 5}) => #{[1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [2 3] [2 4] [2 5]}
```

I'm not sure on the steps to get there though. I have looked through documentation etc but can't find what I'm looking for. Other answer to this deal with lists etc. But I have to use 2 Sets.

What I'm looking at atm is using `doseq[e A]` and inside that `doseq[x B]` then add each vector-pair `[e x]` to a new Set and then return it. This doesn't seem like a standard functional solution though. Am I on the right track? How do I add it to a new Set?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://clojure.github.io/math.combinatorics/#clojure.math.combinatorics/cartesian-product)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cartesian product in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246549/cartesian-product-in-clojure)

Comment: As I stated I have looked through other answers but they use list. Like the one you linked. Rulle's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that using [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for):

```clj
(defn cartesian [A B]
  (set (for [a A
             b B]
         [a b])))

(cartesian #{1 2} #{3 4 5})
;; => #{[2 3] [2 5] [1 4] [1 3] [1 5] [2 4]}
```

Comment: @FelixWillis `(macroexpand '(for [a A b B] [a b]))` is a good place to start :-D

Answer (score 1):

Use [cartesian-product](https://clojure.github.io/math.combinatorics/#clojure.math.combinatorics/cartesian-product) from [clojure.math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics). To get exact result you want (set of vectors), use [`into`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into) with [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) transducer:

```
(into #{} (map vec) (clojure.math.combinatorics/cartesian-product #{1 2} #{3 4 5}))
=> #{[2 3] [2 5] [1 4] [1 3] [1 5] [2 4]}
```